# I have two csv files that i need to merge based on the intersection of the two files i want to drop the columns that weren't repeated

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, merge

For example if file 1 looks like this:

```
 id  col1  col2  col3
 --------------------
  1  aa    bb     cc
  2  dd    ff     gg
```

and file 2 looks like

```
 id  col1  col2  col3  col4
 ---------------------------
  3   qq    ww    ee    tt
```

I want the output file to look like

```
 id   col1   col2   col3
 -----------------------
  1   aa     bb     cc
  2   dd     ff     gg
  3   qq     ww     ee
```

Meaning that I want to merge the files based on the intersection only and I want to discard the columns that were not repeated in both files

I tried the following attempts

```py
df1= pd.read_csv("lastOne.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("Normal.csv")
dfAll=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
```

I also tried df1.combine_first(df2) among many others but all fails to do what I need

Comment: how many such files do you have? you can just try `reindexing` with df1 columns such as `pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).reindex(columns=df1.columns)` or `pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).loc[:,df1.columns]`

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but you chose the wrong axis.

**axis=0** for when you want to add more rows, with similar columns

**axis=1** when you want to add more columns and you have similar rows

The correct answer would be:

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner', axis=0)
```